# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 0

Tags: java

I want to use an `ArrayList` to represent the priority queue. So I want to add item on specific position of the ArrayList. But when I run it, system told me

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   10, Size: 0.

```
public void enqueu(String s, int p) {
    Queue.add(p,s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue test= new PriorityQueue();
    test.enqueu("x",10);
    test.enqueu("Y",1);
    test.enqueu("Z",3);
}
```

Comment: so, size of your ArrayList is 0, you're trying to insert at 10th position, what do you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 0. JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560862/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-index-10-size)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you know what you're doing here. You have to clearly define everything first.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<String> comparator = new StringLengthComparator();
    PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>(10, comparator);
    queue.add("short");
    queue.add("very long indeed");
    queue.add("medium");
    while (queue.size() != 0)
    {
        System.out.println(queue.remove());
    }
}
```

}