# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 0. JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to use an `ArrayList` to represent the priority queue. So I want to add item on specific position of the `ArrayList`. But when I run it, system told me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 0.`

```
public class PriorityQueue 
{
public ArrayList<String> Queue=new ArrayList<>();

public void enqueu(String s, int p)
{
    Queue.add(p,s);
}

public void dequeu()
{
    String temp=Queue.get(Queue.size()-1);
    Queue.remove(temp);
}
public void print()
{
    String[] print=new String[Queue.size()];
    print=Queue.toArray(print);
    for(int i=0;i<Queue.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(print[i]);
    }


}

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     PriorityQueue test= new PriorityQueue();
     test.enqueu("x",10);
     test.enqueu("Y",1);
     test.enqueu("Z",3);

     test.print();
 }}
```

Comment: What debugging attempts have you made? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your `enqueue` doe not make any sense if this is supposed to be a Queue because `enqueue` adds at the end of the `Queue` not at an arbitrary index. Since you call you class Priority Queue, I assume the second parameter for your `enqueue` method will be the priority of the element not it's index. You should probably read some on Queues.

Answer (score 0):

Because the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) for `add(int index, E element)` of `ArrayList` says:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
>
> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range
>   (index < 0 || index > size())

You are doing:

```
test.enqueu("x",10);
```

which calls:

```
Queue.add(10,"x"); // "Queue" is the arrayList
```

You are trying to add an string to index 10, where the size of ArrayList is 0. That means, you are trying this, where **index > size()**. So you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also, think more about your design and what you should do. `Enqueue` does not work this way what you are trying to do.